# Accessing variable from imported class from another React script

Tags: reactjs

I'm importing a class from another script in my main React App, and would like to access a variable within that class from the main App.  Basically the user types something into a textbox, then clicks a button to add that value to a variable.  In the main App I import that class, then have another button to print those values (selectedvalues).  I'm not entirely sure how to do it, but this is my code so far:

Class I am importing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyModule extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            selectedValues: '',
        }
     }

    addValue() {
        this.selectedValues += document.getElementById('textBox1').value + ', '
        return this.selectedValues  
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='textBox1' />
                <button onClick={() => this.addValue()}>Add Value</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default MyModule
```

And where I would like to actually access that value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyModule from './myModule.js'

class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {

        }
     }

    printValues() {
         console.log(document.getElementById('themodule').selectedvalues)
     }

    render() {
        return(
            <MyModule id='themodule' />
            <button onClick={() => printValues()}>Print values</button>
        )
    }
  }

export default App
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use React Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share state between components, or let the parent component (`<App/>` in this case) handle the state and pass it on to the child component (`<MyModule/>`).

Comment: I used to store that kind of variables at topLevel, and then, I send as a property: <MyModule id=... selectedValues={this.state.selectedValues} addValue={this.addValue}

Comment: So define the selected values variable in the `this.state={selectedValues: ''}`, on the App.js side, then how would I get that into the myModule.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** JS-fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/xzehg1by/9/

You can create Refs and access state and methods from it. Something like this.

```
constructor() {
   this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

render() { ... <MyModule id='themodule' ref={this.myRef} /> }

printValues() {
   console.log(this.myRef)
}
```

more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks.  Can I access the state values from MyModule like this?  When console.log this.myRef, it just returns current: null.  I also get a warning saying :`components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`  Not sure how that impacts the functionality

Comment: @Djaenike Yes. You can use refs to access the state and all methods private to MyModule using current. I have created a fiddle for you please check https://jsfiddle.net/xzehg1by/9/

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your state (`selectedValues`) has to go one level up in the React tree. You have to declare it as `App`'s state, and then pass it down to `MyModule` via props.

Btw in `addValue()`, you're not changing any state. And `this.selectedValues` will be undefined. It's `this.state.selectedValues`, and `this.props.selectedValues` once you correct your code.

Comment: well noted... the selectedValues update has a error because it doesn't use the setState

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first read all react concepts and then start working on it. Anyhow i am modifying your code in one way to get your desired functionality but remember this is not best practice you have to use Redux for this kind of features

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyModule extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputValue : ''
        };
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.addValue = this.addValue.bind(this)
    }
    handleInput(e){
        this.setState({
            inputValue : e.target.value
        })
    }
    addValue() {
        this.props.addValue(this.state.inputValue);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text' id='textBox1' onChange={handleInput} />
                <button onClick={this.addValue}>Add Value</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyModule
```

and your main component should be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyModule from './myModule.js'

class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedValues : ''
        };
        this.printValues = this.printValues.bind(this);
        this.addValues = this.addValues.bind(this);
    }

    printValues() {
        console.log(this.state.selectedValues);
    }

    addValues(val){
        this.setState({
            selectedValues : this.state.selectedValues + " , "+val
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <MyModule addValue={this.addValues}/>
            <button onClick={this.printValues} >Print values</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

This should do your work